# Using Case Value to determine other column values

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

I have a requirement where there are 4 case statments and those case statement values are going into 4 different columns. Using 4 different case values in run time i need to determine other column values( around 10) in the same procedure..Any example or suggest the best way to do .

Thought of using all the 4 case in cursor first ..then will open the cursor and first and fetch into the columns and use those column value to determine other values..

Suggestions pls with example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The description is a bit ambiguous, please provide the CASE statement at least or the query you are using. Besides, there are no hashtags on stackoverflow for topics, just use available tags.

Comment: Havent started with the query yet thinking of flow to implement.

Comment: @aadi Where is the data coming from? Is it already in the database? Could you possibly make use of the `MERGE` statement? (Which version of Oracle?)

Comment: If you have no code to show, you should at least provide sample data and expected output. Preferably as [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/).